# C++ Finding tab character in wstring

Tags: c++, find, wstring

I would like to find the tab character in a wstring.

However

```
int n =mywstring.find(L"\t");
```

does not work, "n" is -1, although I know that the tab character is present in the wstring.

What am I missing here?

Thank you for the help!

Edit:

I found that the problem lies in the way I read the wstring from the file.

I am using

```
bool GetLineW(FILE *inFile, wstring &result)
{
wchar_t data[2]={0,0};

result = L"";
do{
    fread(data, sizeof(wchar_t), 1, inFile);

    if (data[0]>=L' ')
        result += data;

    if (data[0]==0x0A)
        break;
}while(!feof(inFile));

if (result.size()>0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Well yeah, `'\t'<' '`. What do you expect? What are you trying to achieve by reading in this way? Why aren't you using [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)?

Comment: @BoBTFish My file is encoded in Notepad with the "Unicode" encoding. If I use getline, I do not get Unicode characters, but Unicode values (the Unicode characters are not correctly decoded).

Comment: @BoBTFish What do you mean by "Well yeah, '\t'<' '."?

Comment: @tmighty he means your condition `if (data[0]>=L' ')` is ignoring any '\t' because its char value is lower than a space.

Comment: I think I will stop using Unicode files and just switch to UTF8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wstring::find` and `string::find` returns `npos` in case the character is not found, which is equivalent to -1.

A return value of 0 means that the character has been found at the first index of the string, since indexes start at 0.